# Jena getNsPrefixUri returning null (how to define base URI for OWL ontologies?)

Tags: java, xml-namespaces, jena, owl, ontology

I'm trying to create a individual (instance) using [Jena](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/ontology/) with the method below:

```
public void createInstance(String name) {
        String NS = ontology.getNsPrefixURI("http://james.miranda.br/Onto");
        OntClass class = ontology.createClass(NS + "Requisito");
        Individual instance = class.createIndividual(NS + name);
        System.out.println("Instance created:" + instance.getURI());
    }
```

`ontology` is a OntModel instance based on [this ontology](http://pastebin.com/cxdv5Tp8) (some terms are in Portuguese). This method is not working, because the `getNsPrefixURI` is returning null.

When I iterate over the classes using the code below:

```
ExtendedIterator<OntClass> classIterator = ontology.listClasses(); 
        while (classIterator.hasNext()) { 
            OntClass ontClass = classIterator.next(); 
            System.out.println(ontClass.toString()); 
        }
```

the (partial) result is:

> http://james.miranda.br/Onto#Requisito
>
> http://james.miranda.br/Onto#Micro
>
> http://james.miranda.br/Onto#Certo
>
> http://james.miranda.br/Onto#Objetivo
>
> http://james.miranda.br/Onto#Individuo

Using `getNsPrefixURI("")` I have the NS `http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl` and my method does not work too. I was looking for how to define the base uri here in SO, but the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573320/get-base-namespace-from-an-owl-ontology) did not work in my case.

Trying to get the all the namespaces, I used the code:

```
Map<String,String> list = ontology.getNsPrefixMap();
System.out.println(list.toString());
```

The result is: `{=http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#, xsd=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#, rdfs=http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#, owl=http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#, rdf=http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#}`.

I didn't receive the prefix for "http://james.miranda.br/Onto". Should it be declared anywhere?

Are there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: In your ontology I don't see a prefix declaration for http://james.miranda.br/Onto. You have defined the ontology IRI, but that's not a namespace declaration for http://james.miranda.br/Onto. Namespace in RDFXML are defined by  `xmlns:PREFIX_NAME=PREFIX_URI...` as you can see from the others like `rdfs`, `owl`, etc.

Comment: @AKSW Thanks for your comment, but let me ask, should I replace the `rdf:about="http://james.miranda.br/Onto"` in each tag for anything?

Comment: I don't exactly know what you want to achieve.

Comment: And I'm wondering why you write RDFXML manually, as it's mostly there for tools. It's much easier to use TURTLE instead as long as you only have RDF/RDFS data.

Comment: @AKSW I created the ontology using Protégé and saved it as "RDF/XML". Saving it as TURTLE serialization is better? I'm trying to create some individuals and reasoning on them. I tried to use "OWL/XML" before, but its not work with Jena.

Comment: Ok, I see. What means better? Jena can read both formats, Turtle and RDF/XML. I don't know how Protege adds the prefixes, maybe there is an option to add the one you need.

Comment: On the best/worst format, I'm new on SemWeb so I'm sorry for any mistake, but by my understanding, when I save my file using RDF rather than OWL, I lose the possibility of some inferences ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1813585/3943162)). The same occurs when I save it in TURTLE serialization? Anyway, in this meanwhile I'll try to save it in TURTLE and also to include the base URI in Protégé. Thanks for all your help

Comment: OWL can be serialized in formats like RDF/XML, Turtle, N-Triples, OWL Functional syntax, etc. . This means that nothing is lost, otherwise it wouldn't be a valid serialization format and obviously not supported by an OWL ontology editor like Protege.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of `getNsPrefixURI` says "Get the URI bound to a specific prefix, null if there isn't one."  i.e. prefix in, URI out.

"http://james.miranda.br/Onto" is not a legal prefix.

There is no namespace prefix for http://james.miranda.br/Onto.

This does **not** set a prefix:

```
<Ontology rdf:about="http://james.miranda.br/Onto">
```

We would expect to see:

```
xmlns:onto="http://james.miranda.br/Onto#"
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. After include it in my ontology, should I include the `onto` prefix in each tag? Are there any way to include it using Protégé?

Comment: The xmlns:onto can go along side the other xmlns:????. How that happens on protege, I don't know - I don't use it.

Comment: I also don't know since I'm starting to use it just now. I'll accept the advice of @AKSW and save it in another serialization format (TURTLE). Thank you for your response anyway.